# VueJs View not updating after array.push()

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Here is my View

```
<div class="store-list" id="store-list">
<div class="store-list__store" v-for="store in stores">
    <div class="store-list__store--info">
        <h5 class="store-list__store--address">
            {{store.address}}
        </h5>
        <div class="store-list__store--meta">
            <i class="icon-location-store-small"></i>
            <span class="store-list__store--type">
                {{store.type}}
            </span>
            <span class="store-list__store--distance">
                <i class="icon-location"></i>
                {{store.distance}} km
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="store-list__store--picker store-list__store--stockstatus">
        <p class="store-list__store-stockstatus store-list__store-stockstatus--instock" v-if="store.stock">
            <i class="icon-check"></i>
            I lager
        </p>
        <p class="store-list__store-stockstatus" v-else>
            <i class="icon-remove"></i>
            Ej i lager
        </p>
        <a class="store-list__store--pick-store js-go-store">Välj butik</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my Vue instance which is supposed to create a list of stores coming from and Ajax call. On first call the list is created but whenever i search for a new set of stores the array changes and updates. The console.log shows the changes on every call but the rendered view remains the same.

```
const storeListVm = new Vue({
        el: '#stock-status',
        data() {
            return {
                stores: [],
                openhoursToday: '',
                showOnlyInStock: true
            };
        },
        methods: {
            fetchStoresWithStock: function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: dataUrl,
                    dataType: 'json',
                }).done((data) => {
                    for(let i = 0; i < data.facilities.length; i++) {
                        this.stores.push(data.facilities[i]);
                    };

                    console.log(this.stores);
                });
            }
        }
});
```

Can someone please help me figure out why the array changes but not the view? I've tried Vue.set as well

Comment: Is your code example exactly as it appears in your application? Or did you modify it at all for the post?

Comment: It's as this post but without declatation of dataUrl

Comment: I can't identify anything wrong with your code, it should work. Can you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: This might be the cause: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key

Comment: The new data is being fetched whenever "place_changed" is being triggered on google autocomplete. Is it a problem that the Vue instance is being recreated each time this happens?

Comment: Yea don't recreate the vue instance at each update. If storeList is a separate view then use a [global event bus](http://vuetips.com/global-event-bus) to notify it of the `place_changed` event.

Comment: Then that might be the issue, thank you

Comment: If that solves your problem, then post it here so that I will write an answer to help future readers

Comment: @smac89 Yes that did the trick! As long as I only create the Vue instance once everything works